# Show all jQuery TipTip tooltips on click

Tags: jquery, tiptip

Developing with jQuery's TipTip (http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin).

What I need is to show all of the tooltips on a page at ones, on some event (page loaded or if it is clicked on some link).

Is possible to achieve it with this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin uses only one element and repositions and changes content dynamically. This is typical of majority of tooltip plugins. You would need to modify both css and plugin to allow use of class instead of ID for tip element and to extend it to have more than one available at a time

Comment: Not trivial based on source code, but the source code is structured fairly nicely to enable you to repurpose the code. It'd be a fairly extensive rewrite, but it's good base material.

Comment: Tnx, manage to do what I need with Gips - http://www.egrappler.com/jquery-clean-and-simple-tooltips-gips/